# How to deserialize XML if the return type could be an Error or Success object

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am working with an XML based API that as its root node can either return a `SuccessResponse` or a `ErrorResponse`.

I am using the below to deserialize the data but I am not sure how to handle the case of the return not being a `SuccessResponse`. 
What is the best way to handle the situation where the returned XML isn't in the expected format?

I know I could do a hack way and look for the occurrance of either `SuccessResponse` or `ErrorResponse` but that doesn't feel right.

```
    TheIconicApiResult result = this.apiService.SendGetRequest("GetProducts", new List<AbstractParam>() { new FilterParam("live"), new LimitParam(5000) });
    IXmlSerialiser xmlSerialiser = new XmlSerialiser();
    var xmlBody = xmlSerialiser.ParseXML<SuccessResponse>(result.ResponseBody);

    public TObject ParseXML<TObject>(string xml)
    {
        using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(GetMemoryStream(xml)))
        {
            XmlSerializer serialiser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TObject));
            return (TObject)serialiser.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You must hack the response format. Since that's not a standard response structure serializer would understand.

Comment: return null if there is an error.

Comment: But I want to deserialising into an error object so that I can see what the error was. I've gone with the hightech solution of checking if the string contains error or success before deserialising

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In situations where you have an XML stream containing one of several possible document types, you can construct an `XmlSerializer` for each type and call [`XmlSerializer.CanDeserialize(XmlReader)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.candeserialize.aspx) to successively test whether the document can be deserialized into that type.  This method does not advance the `XmlReader` past the root element so it can be called multiple times without re-reading the stream.

For instance, you could introduce the following extension method:

```
public static partial class XmlSerializerExtensions
{
    public static object DeserializePolymorphicXml(this string xml, params Type[] types)
    {
        using (var textReader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            return textReader.DeserializePolymorphicXml(types);
        }
    }

    public static object DeserializePolymorphicXml(this TextReader textReader, params Type[] types)
    {
        if (textReader == null || types == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings { CloseInput = false }; // Let caller close the input.
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(textReader, settings))
        {
            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
                if (serializer.CanDeserialize(xmlReader))
                    return serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
            }
        }
        throw new XmlException("Invalid root type.");
    }
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
var xmlBody = result.ResponseBody.DeserializePolymorphicXml(typeof(SuccessResponse), typeof(FailResponse));
if (xmlBody is SuccessResponse)
{
    // Handle successful response
}
else if (xmlBody is FailResponse)
{
    // Handle failed response
}
else
{
    // unknown response
    throw new InvalidOperationException("unknown response");
}
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7Ied0Z).

Comment: This looks fantastic! I will implement this today and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Just implemented this and it works very well. My code is much cleaner. I think there is no need for the else in your usage example above as the deserializer will throw an exception if the type is not known anyway. Thanks!