# Serialize XML file based on Tags (e.g. StartTags, EndTags)

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-4, xmlserializer

Thanks for reading this ;)

I want to serialize an xml file but the Tag names will be different based on the file. I have a class file for each of the Config file so that i can create an object based on the which file.

What i need right now is a way to identify the Tag names(e.g. ) so that i can assign it to its respective Objects(e.g. James.cs). Also able to get to content of the tags.

I'm currently using ASP.NET but cant find any libraries that suit my needs. HALP!

Comment: You can construct multiple `XmlSerializers` and check [`CanDeserialize(XmlReader)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.candeserialize.aspx) sequentially for each as explained in [How to deserialize XML if the return type could be an Error or Success object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44234061/3744182).

Comment: And if you are actually asking [*How to Deserialize XML document*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/364253/3744182), see for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document/364410#364410).

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the tag name en then use the XmlSerializer to Deserialize the objects, this generic function can help you with that.

```
public static TObject XmlDeserialize<TObject>(XDocument xmlToDeserialize) 
{
    TObject deserializedObject = default(TObject);
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TObject));
    using (System.IO.TextReader reader = new System.IO.StringReader(xmlToDeserialize.ToString()))
    {
        deserializedObject = (TObject)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

    return deserializedObject;
}
```

See a run example in: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5ViI1L