# XML deserializer of abstract class cannot identify concrete class

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, abstract-class

I have a input XML which I want to deserialize into a concrete class which derives from a known abstract base class. Example:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace SerializationTest
{
    [XmlInclude(typeof(ConcreteFoo))]
    public abstract class AbstractFoo
    {
    }

    [XmlRoot("ConcreteFoo")]
    public class ConcreteFoo : AbstractFoo
    {
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var xml = "<ConcreteFoo />";
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AbstractFoo));
            using (var stream = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                var obj = serializer.Deserialize(stream); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The serializer doesn't recognize the `ConcreteFoo` as derived class of `AbstractFoo` and gives following exception:

> InvalidOperationException: < ConcreteFoo xmlns='' > was not expected.

The given input XML is fixed and was created using the concrete class in serialization. Any hints?

Comment: `[XmlInclude]` will cause an [`xsi:type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca1ks327.aspx) attribute to be generated.  It won't change the root element name.  If the XML is fixed and might have multiple roots, you can construct multiple `XmlSerializer` instances for each as shown in [How to deserialize XML if the return type could be an Error or Success object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44234061/3744182).

Comment: A quick way to determine why this doesn't work is to do the reverse - create a `ConcreteFoo` and serialize it. You'll see the output is different to the input in the question.