# Element name for root derived classess with XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I am trying to write (and later read) a log in XML format. Log in my case is a stream of events, each having a corresponding class with XML serialization-compatible declaration. A trivial case is:

```
public abstract class Base {
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
public class A: Base{}
public class B: Base{}
```

When I create XmlSerializer, I pass `typeof(A), typeof(B)` as the `extraTypes` parameter. That generates

```
<Base xsi:type="A" Value="42"/>
<Base xsi:type="B" Value="42"/>
```

I'd like to see

```
<A Value="42"/>
<B Value="42"/>
```

or at least

```
<A xsi:type="A" Value="42"/>
```

instead for readability.

Is it possible to do without manually generating serialization code and nesting?

I could create an instance of XmlSerializer per class, but I am not sure later I'd be able to deserialize its output.

NOTE: I am streaming, e.g. I am writing new instances of `A` or `B` as soon as they arrive into existing `XmlWriter`.

Comment: There's no way to get the "at least" format.  You can get the `<A Value="42"/>` format by creating an instance-specific serializer.  Then later, to deserialize, you can construct an `XmlSerializer` for each possible type and call [`XmlSerializer.CanDeserialize(XmlReader)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.candeserialize.aspx) to test whether each serializer can be used, as shown in the answer to [How to deserialize XML if the return type could be an Error or Success object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44248192/3744182).

Comment: @dbc , this approach works, but I wonder what is the performance penalty for deserialization.

Comment: You would have to construct multiple serializers, but this only causes one performance hit per session, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/23897145/3744182 for details.  Then, since `XmlSerializer.CanDeserialize(XmlReader)` doesn't advance the reader, it must just be checking the root element name and namespace, which is quite performant.  But beyond that see https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: @dbc , yeah, I switched to multiple serializers following the same logic :)

Comment: OK, so mark as a duplicate then?

Comment: @dbc , I guess it might be considered a duplicate then. Got a suitable answer anyway.