# XML Deserialize, loading an instance of a saved character

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, serialization

Project in Windows Form, the goal is for the player to store a character in an XML and later load the stored character.

**Error:** 
System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is an error in XML document (2, 2).'
InvalidOperationException: < Berserker xmlns=''> was not expected.

```
        public static PlayerBase LoadGame()
        {
        if (!File.Exists(PlayerSettingsFile))
        {
            return new PlayerBase();
        }

        using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(PlayerSettingsFile))
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PlayerBase));
            return (PlayerBase)ser.Deserialize(stream);
        }

    }
```

What I assume is the problem is that the player stores the derived class of PlayerBase, which in this case is a Berserker. So when loading it's looking for the keyword of PlayerBase and it finds Berserker?

If that's so. Is there a way of simplify the code to check which class the player created for it's hero?

Here's the creating part,

```
 private void Btn_SaveChar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = Txt_CharName.Text;
        string selectedClass = Cbo_CharClass.Text;

        EntityGender gender = Rdo_GenderMale.Checked ? EntityGender.Male: EntityGender.Female;

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectedClass))
        {
            PlayerBase hero = new PlayerBase();
            if (selectedClass == "Berserker")
            {
                hero = new Berserker(name, gender);
                FileManager.StoreCharacter(hero);
            }
```

XML file,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Berserker xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Name>Fred</Name>
  <Strength>10</Strength>
  <Dexterity>5</Dexterity>
  <Wisdom>5</Wisdom>
  <Health>25</Health>
  <Gender>Male</Gender>
  <CharacterClass>Berserker</CharacterClass>
</Berserker>
```

Comment: We need to see the xml.  This is a common error but can occur for may reasons.

Comment: Added the XML at the bottom.

Comment: You could use [`XmlSerializerExtensions.DeserializePolymorphicXml(this TextReader textReader, params Type[] types)`] from [How to deserialize XML if the return type could be an Error or Success object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44248192/3744182) and pass in all possible derived types of `PlayerBase`.  Internally it calls It calls [`XmlSerializer.CanDeserialize(XmlReader)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.candeserialize.aspx) for each possible type.

Comment: Great! It works, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following deserializer

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        public static void Main()
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Berserker));
            Berserker berserker = (Berserker)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        }
    }
    public class Berserker
    {
         public string Name { get; set;}
         public int Strength { get; set;}
         public int Dexterity { get; set;}
         public int Wisdom { get; set;}
         public int Health { get; set;}
         public string Gender { get; set;}
         public string CharacterClass { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, changing to check for typeof Berserker made it work!
Which is what I sort of assumed. So now I need to check which heroclass that the player created so it loads the correct one? Thought it would work with PlayerBase since they all derive from that one.

Comment: How would I go by to check which class the player choosed for the typeof?

Comment: if (typeof(Berserker) == berserker.GetType())