# XML File - Two versions - Same data - Attribute to Element + name change

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I will be receiving this two xmls

```
<XML>
    <Name>Test</Name>
</XML>
```

or

```
<XML1 Name1="Test">
</XML1>
```

I wanted to know if there is a way to handle the value for the element "Name" and the attribute "Name1" using just one variable.

I tried this but when I executed the serializer function (`XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XML));`) it fails at run time with this message:

> "There was an error reflecting type 'XMLSerializerTest.XML'."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ftoA.png)

Using the `XmlChoiceIdentifier` didn't work, but I'm new to handling XML so there might be something wrong. At the end what I want to do is receive one format and be able to change to the other format. I wrote a simple example here but I want to propagate the solution across an entire project.

This is the class I created:

```cs
namespace XMLSerializerTest
{
    [XmlType("XML", Namespace = "")]
    [XmlRoot("XML1")] //This doesn't handle multiple root names
    public class XML
    {
        [XmlElement("Name")]
        [XmlAttribute("Name1")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is what I'm doing from Main to try and test it:

```cs
//This is the line giving the error I mentioned 
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XML));
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("[FileLocation.xml]");
//Do something to change to a diff "format"
XML xmltest = (XML)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(sr);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Test1.xml");
sw.Close();
```

Comment: Since the root element names differ you can construct serializers for each and use `XmlSerializer.CanDeserialize(XmlReader)` to test which applies.  See: [How to deserialize XML if the return type could be an Error or Success object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44234061/3744182).

Comment: *There was an error reflecting type 'XMLSerializerTest.XML* - can you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] that reproduces the exception?  Also, might you please [edit] your question to include your exception details as **text** rather than as a screen shot?  Stack Overflow policy is that you should include your code, errors and data (XML, etc) as text, not as an image.  For why, see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812).

Comment: You can't have two square  brackets items above the same property.  Use either XmlElement or XmlAttribute, not both.

Answer (score 0):

First option:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml("<XML><Name>Test</Name></XML>");
string NameValue = document.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
```

Second option:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml("<XML1 Name1=\"Test\"></XML1>");
string NameValue = document.ChildNodes[0].Attributes[0].Value;
```

Third option:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class XML1
{

    private string name1Field;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Name1
    {
        get
        {
            return this.name1Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.name1Field = value;
        }
    }
}

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XML1));
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader("<XML1 Name1=\"Test\"></XML1>"))
{
     XML1 root = (XML1)(serializer.Deserialize(reader));
     string NameValue = root.Name1;
}
```

Fourth option:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class XML
{

    private string nameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }
}

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XML));
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader("<XML><Name>Test</Name></XML>"))
{
     XML root = (XML)(serializer.Deserialize(reader));
     string NameValue = root.Name;
}
```

For the last two options, there is a little trick that will help you to automatically create classes based on your XML file.
If you are working on .NET 4.5 project(or newer), you can just Special Paste your XML file as classes.
 1. Copy your XML file's content to clipboard.
 2. In editor, select place where you want your classes to be pasted 
 3. From the menu, select EDIT> Paste Special > Paste XML As Classes

Comment: Thank you! After a deeper analysis we decided to just have two separate solutions to handle the different xml format.