# How does "System.Messaging" system recognises the types of the objects it sends and receives?

Tags: c#, xml, polymorphism, messaging, msmq

**Edit: root cause of the question**

I'm working on an application, that uses [`System.Messaging`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.messaging) and XML serialisation via [`XmlMessageFormatter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.messaging.xmlmessageformatter).

I would like to send an object, let's say `Class1`, having an ID field:

```
public class Class1{
  public long Id1;
}
```

I would also like to send another object, let's say `Class16`, having another ID field:

```
public class Class16{
  public long Id16;
}
```

In XML, both need to look like:

```
<HM>Human_Message
  <ID>Own_Identifier</ID>
</HM>
```

In order to achieve this, I'm working with following `[Xml]`-like configurations:

Class1:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "HM")]
public class Class1{
  [XmlElement(ElementName = "ID")]
  public long Id1;
}
```

Class16:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "HM")]
public class Class16{
  [XmlElement(ElementName = "ID")]
  public long Id16;
}
```

As you see, the XML body will indeed be equal for both classes.

Is this even possible?

**Edit: original question**

I have a basic class (simple class), from which there are several subclasses (about 27 of them), inheriting from it.

I'm using standard C# `System.Messaging` system for sending objects back and forth.

Very simplified:

**Sending side:**

I have a MessageQueue, doing:

```
subClass1 Obj1 = subClass1(...);
...
Basic_Class Obj_To_Be_Sent = Basic_Class(Obj1);
System.Messaging.Message message = new System.Messaging.Message(Obj_To_Be_Sent);
obj_MessageQueue.Send(message, ...);
```

When checking `Obj_To_Be_Sent`, the type is correct.

Once this is sent, when I have a look at <kbd>Computer Management</kbd>, <kbd>Services and Applications</kbd>, <kbd>Message Queuing</kbd>, ..., <kbd>Properties</kbd>, I see the message, but I can't verify if the type is still correct.

**Receiving side:**

I have an `_xmlMessageFormatter`, containing (amongst others):

```
System.Type[] messageTypes = new System.Type[27];
messageTypes[0] = typeof(SubClass1);
...
messageTypes[15] = typeof(SubClass16);
...
message = this._receiveQueue.Receive();
Basic_Class general = (Basic_Class)this._xmlMessageFormatter.Read(message);
Type objectType= general.GetType();
```

To my surprise, `objectType` is wrong (it is believed to be `SubClass16`).

This application has worked fine before, but now something seems to fail. The biggest problem I have is that I don't know how to check the steps between sending the message and getting the type of the received message.

Does anybody have knowledge on <kbd>Computer Management</kbd>, <kbd>Services and Applications</kbd>, <kbd>Message Queuing</kbd>, ..., how can I check if the object type on the sending side is ok?
Does anybody have knowledge on `_xmlFormatter.Read()` and `GetType()`? (Already after the `Read()`, the watch-window mentions the Type of `general` to be wrong)

Thanks in advance

**Edit after more investigation**

I delete my own answer as the problem is not completely solved.

Meanwhile I've discovered that `[XmlRoot]` entries are causing the mentioned issues: I've been using the same `[XmlRoot]` entry for different classes.

Is there a way to differentiate?

For your information, I've already tried the following but it did not work:

Class1:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "HM", DataType = "subClass1", Namespace="Namespace")]
public class subClass1 : Basic_Class
```

Class2:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "HM", DataType = "subClass16", Namespace="Namespace")]
public class subClass16 : Basic_Class
```

while the `_xmlFormatter.TargetTypes` contained entries like:

```
Name = "subClass1" FullName="Namespace.Class1"
Name = "subClass16" FullName="Namespace.Class16"
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Can you share a [mcve] including demo client + server code?  Your psuedocode is not close to compilable, and basic issues like *is `typeof(Base_Class)` included in `messageTypes`* are unclear.

Comment: Reference source for `XmlMessageFormatter.Read(Message message)` and `XmlMessageFormatter.Write(Message message, object obj)` is [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Messaging/System/Messaging/XmlMessageFormatter.cs,6fbc12cc7602ffe5,references).  The serialization algorithm is simple: it serializes the incoming object using a default `XmlSerializer`.  For deserialization, it cycles through all target types and calls `XmlSerializer.CanDeserialize(XmlReader)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44248192/3744182) on each.

Comment: So if the deserialized type is wrong that means that the `[XmlRoot]` declarations are somehow inconsistent between client and server, or you have types with duplicate root names & namespaces in your target types, or are making some other similar mistake.  No way to say for sure without a [mcve].

Comment: Try serializing to XML on the client side using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2434558/3744182), and on the server side try deserializing the same XML string to a `SubClass16` using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26026980/3744182).  Does it work?  Then your root type names are inconsistent or nonunique.

Comment: Has server changed?  You are writing data from client to server and then parsing the response.  There is nothing in between with the client code.  So either your send data is different from the past or the server has changed.  It is also possible that you recompiled with a different version of Net.  Try using an old executable.

Comment: @dbc: you talk about nonunique root type names. I've edited my question and added the root cause of the problem. Are you saying that using one `<HM>` tag for different classes is forbidden?

Comment: @Dominique if all the XML messages have same root element, then the deserializer cannot know exactly which type it has to deserialize the document to, because it uses xml root to uniquely identify target type. If you have a strict requirement for all messages to have the same xml root, than you would need to use custom serializer rules and maybe add the target type to an attribute or something.

Comment: Why do you need the XML to be identical?

Comment: If for some reason the root name needs to be the same, would an added `xsi:type` attribute be acceptable?

Comment: @dbc: that might be a possibility, how to implement this? (And what would the XML look like in that case?)

Comment: @Dominique - it would look like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xxl2TI

Comment: @Dominique - answer updated with a custom `IMessageFormatter` that uses `xsi:type` to include type information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL/DR**

[`XmlMessageFormatter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.messaging.xmlmessageformatter?view=netframework-4.8) recognizes the type of object received by inspecting the XML [root element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element) name and namespace URI and finding a compatible type among the provided [`TargetTypes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.messaging.xmlmessageformatter.targettypes?view=netframework-4.8):

> Specifies the set of possible types that will be deserialized by the formatter from the message provided.

Thus you need to specify distinct [`XmlRootAttribute.ElementName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.elementname?view=netframework-4.8) root element names for each of your derived types rather than using the same name `"HM"` for all of them.  Having done so, you should be able to send and receive them using `XmlMessageFormatter` without loss of type information.

If for whatever reason this ***cannot*** be done and you need to use the same root name "HM" on all your classes, you will need to implement your own custom [`IMessageFormatter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.messaging.imessageformatter?view=netframework-4.8) based on `XmlMessageFormatter` that encodes the type via some other mechanism such as an `xsi:type` attribute.

**Explanation**

You are using `XmlMessageFormatter` to send and receive instances of a polymorphic type hierarchy formatted as XML.  Internally this serializer uses [`XmlSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netframework-4.8) to serialize to and deserialize from XML.  This serializer supports two different mechanisms for exchanging polymorphic types:

1. Type information may be specified by using different (root) element names for each type.

   Since the root element name is given by default by the class name, you may not need to indicate different root element names via metadata, but if you do, use [`XmlRootAttribute.ElementName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.elementname?view=netframework-4.8):

   > The name of the XML root element that is generated and recognized in an XML-document instance. The default is the name of the serialized class.

   If you were to opt for this mechanism, your classes would look something like:

   ```
   [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Basic_Class", Namespace="Namespace")]
   public class Basic_Class
   {
   }

   [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Class1", Namespace="Namespace")]
   public class Class1 : Basic_Class
   {
   }

   [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Class16", Namespace="Namespace")]
   public class Class16 : Basic_Class
   {
   }
   ```

   When using this mechanism, construct an `XmlSerializer` for the concrete type to be serialized.
2. If a common root element is emitted for all subtypes, type information may be specified via an `xsi:type` attribute.

   This attribute, short for `{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type`, is a [w3c standard attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_type) that allows an element to explicitly assert its type, e.g. when it is a polymorphic subtype of the expected element type.  `XmlSerializer` [supports this attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca1ks327.aspx) and will use it to determine the actual type of object to deserialize for such a polymorphic type.

   If you were to opt for this mechanism, your classes would look something like:

   ```
   [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Basic_Class", Namespace="Namespace")]
   [XmlInclude(typeof(Class1)), XmlInclude(typeof(Class16))] // Include all subtypes here!
   public class Basic_Class
   {
   }

   [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Class1", Namespace="Namespace")]
   public class Class1 : Basic_Class
   {
   }

   [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Class16", Namespace="Namespace")]
   public class Class16 : Basic_Class
   {
   }
   ```

   When using this mechanism, construct a serializer for the shared base type `Basic_Class` rather than the concrete type.

But, of these two mechanisms, only the first is supported by `XmlMessageFormatter`, as can be seen from the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Messaging/System/Messaging/XmlMessageFormatter.cs,6fbc12cc7602ffe5,references).  The [`Write(Message message, object obj)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Messaging/System/Messaging/XmlMessageFormatter.cs,220) simply constructs or uses a default serializer for the concrete type of the incoming object:

> ```
> Type serializedType = obj.GetType();
> XmlSerializer serializer = null;
> if (this.targetSerializerTable.ContainsKey(serializedType))
>    serializer = (XmlSerializer)this.targetSerializerTable[serializedType];
> else
> {
>    serializer = new XmlSerializer(serializedType);
>    this.targetSerializerTable[serializedType] = serializer;
> }
>
> serializer.Serialize(stream, obj);
> ```

As the serializer is constructed using `obj.GetType()`, the root element name will be the name specified for the derived, concrete class, and `xsi:type` information will not be included.

The [`Read(Message message)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Messaging/System/Messaging/XmlMessageFormatter.cs,195) method cycles through default serializers constructed for the `TargetTypes` and uses the first for which [`XmlSerializer.CanDeserialize(XmlReader)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.candeserialize?view=netframework-4.8) returns `true`:

> ```
> foreach (XmlSerializer serializer in targetSerializerTable.Values)
> {
>    if (serializer.CanDeserialize(reader))
>        return serializer.Deserialize(reader);
> }
> ```

This method in turn simply checks to see whether the root element name and namespace are the compatible with the type to be deserialized.  And this is why you need to use different root element names for each concrete type.

**Implementing your own `IMessageFormatter`**.

As explained above, `XmlMessageFormatter` only supports polymorphism via different root element names.  If this is not acceptable, you will need to implement your `IMessageFormatter` that encodes the type via some other mechanism such as the `xsi:type` attribute described above.

For instance, the following `IMessageFormatter` supports serializing and deserializing via a supplied `XmlSerializer`:

```
public class OverrideXmlMessageFormatter : IMessageFormatter
{
    readonly XmlSerializer serializer;

    public OverrideXmlMessageFormatter(XmlSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (serializer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.serializer = serializer;
    }

    #region IMessageFormatter Members

    public bool CanRead(Message message)
    {
        if (message == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var stream = message.BodyStream;
        bool canRead;
        try
        {
            using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(message.BodyStream))
                canRead = serializer.CanDeserialize(reader);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            canRead = false;
        }
        message.BodyStream.Position = 0; // reset stream in case CanRead is followed by Deserialize
        return canRead;
    }

    public object Read(Message message)
    {
        if (message == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(message.BodyStream))
            return serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

    public void Write(Message message, object obj)
    {
        if (message == null || obj == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        serializer.Serialize(stream, obj);
        message.BodyStream = stream;
        message.BodyType = 0;
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICloneable Members

    public object Clone()
    {
        return new OverrideXmlMessageFormatter(serializer);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then to send and receive messages of type `Class1` and/or `Class16`, define the following `XmlSerializerCache.MessagingSerializer`:

```
public static class XmlSerializerCache
{
    static XmlSerializer CreateSharedSerializer(Type baseType, Type[] extraTypes, string rootName, string rootNamespace)
    {
        // baseType could be typeof(object) if there is no common base type.
        return new XmlSerializer(baseType,
                                 null,
                                 extraTypes,
                                 new XmlRootAttribute { ElementName = rootName, Namespace = rootNamespace },
                                 null);
    }

    static XmlSerializer serializer = CreateSharedSerializer(
        // The base type for the classes you want to send.  Could be object if there is no more derived base type.
        typeof(object),
        // Add all the derived types of the classes you want to send
        new[] { typeof(Class1), typeof(Class16) },
        // Your required root element name.
        "MH",
        // Your required root element namespace.
        "");

    // The serializer must be statically cached to avoid a severe memory leak, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897145/memory-leak-using-streamreader-and-xmlserializer
    public static XmlSerializer MessagingSerializer { get { return serializer; } }
}
```

And set

```
IMessageFormatter _xmlMessageFormatter = new OverrideXmlMessageFormatter(XmlSerializerCache.MessagingSerializer);
```

You will need to use this formatter on both the sending and receiving sides.

The XML sent will look like (for `Class1`):

```xml
<MH xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xsi:type="Class1">
  <ID>10101</ID>
</MH>
```

**Notes**

- [`XmlRootAttribute.DataType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.datatype?view=netframework-4.8) is not used in specifying polymorphic type information.  Instead it can be used to indicate that the element contains a value of some specific XML primitive type such as `dateTime`, `duration`, etc:

  > An XSD (XML Schema Document) data type.

  As such setting this value is not helpful in your application.
- Some related questions about `XmlSerializer` and polymorphism include:

  - *[Using XmlSerializer to serialize derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1643139/3744182)*
  - *[How to deserialize XML if the return type could be an Error or Success object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44234061/3744182)*
- When serializing to XML with an `XmlSerializer` with attribute overrides, you must statically cache and reuse the serializer to avoid a severe memory leak.  See *[Memory Leak using StreamReader and XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23897145/3744182)* for why.
- If you do implement your own `IMessageFormatter` you could hypothetically implement your own messaging format using a different serializer such as Json.NET.